# React Native Web Image component not showing image

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native, react-native-web

I have an Image component which I am using to load an image into a header for my application. I can create a border for where the image is supposed to be but am unable to get the image to properly load. Here is the code where I am loading the image from

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, Image } from 'react-native';

class BackButton extends React.Component {
  
    render() {
        return (
            <Image source={require('./assets/images/arrow.png')} style={styles.image} />
        );
    }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    image: {
      width: '24px',
      height: '24px',
      borderWidth: 1
    }
  });

export default BackButton;
```

And here is where this component is being called

```
import { SafeAreaView, View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import AppText from './assets/text/AppText'
import AppTextHeader from './assets/text/AppTextHeader'
import BackButton from './BackButton'

const Header = ({ onBack, title }) => (
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.headerContainer}>
    <View style={styles.header}>
      <View style={styles.headerLeft}>
        <BackButton/>  
      </View>    
      <View style={styles.headerCenter}>
        <AppTextHeader>
          {title}
        </AppTextHeader>
        {/* <Text accessibilityRole="heading" aria-level="3" style={styles.title}>{title}</Text> */}
      </View>
      <View style={styles.headerRight}/>
    </View>
  </SafeAreaView>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    minHeight: 76
  },
  headerCenter: {
    flex: 1,
    order: 2
  },
  headerLeft: {
    order: 1,
    width: 54,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  headerRight: {
    order: 3,
    width: 54
  },
});

export default Header;
```

What could be causing the image to fail to load?

Comment: In case anyone wants to view the full project, you can view it here https://github.com/nimbusdin/stackreactnative

Comment: try the code without  stylesheet

Comment: I took out StyleSheet and just left it as a styles object but still the same

Comment: try it without styles maybe the problem is in style

Comment: I tried it without styles but no luck

Comment: try to change the image with text to check if the problem is in the path or not

Comment: When I change image with text, the text appears just fine

Comment: When I use a URL of an online image for the image, the image appears correctly. This problem only occurs when I use the require('./filename.png') method of showing images

Answer (score 3):

This was fixed by using import rather than require

```
import imgSrc from './arrow.png';
```

rather than

```
const imgSrc = require('./arrow.png');
```

Comment: This results in a build error: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ImageSourcePropType'`

Comment: Can you show your solution? Your project at github.com/nimbusdin/stackreactnative shows the problem, not how you solved it.

Comment: `import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, Image } from 'react-native';

import backButton from './../assets/images/arrow.png'

class BackButton extends React.Component {
  
    render() {
        return (
            <Image source={backButton} style={styles.image} />
        );
    }
}

var styles = {
    image: {
      width: '24px',
      height: '24px',
    }
  };

export default BackButton;`

Comment: @HyunKim is this documented anywhere? If so, can you share the link?

Comment: If you end-up getting a "Cannot find module 'foo.png' or it's corresponding type" error in your typescript project, do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71100012/246887

Answer (score 3):

You need to do something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, Image } from 'react-native';
import imgSrc from './arrow.png';

class BackButton extends React.Component {
  
    render() {
        return (
            <Image source={{ uri: imgSrc } style={styles.image} />
        );
    }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    image: {
      width: '24px',
      height: '24px',
      borderWidth: 1
    }
  });

export default BackButton;
```

Comment: it fixed web but causes error in andorid and ios? any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Expo, delete .expo & run again. It worked for me.