# Cannot find module 'file-name.png' or its corresponding type declarations - typescript react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i'm trying to import a png in my typescript react project like so:
`import logo from 'assets/Logo.svg';`

I'm getting this TS error though:
`Cannot find module 'assets/Logo.svg' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`

Any idea why this is? I have attached my `tsconfig.json` file below in case I have configured something incorrectly:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to import svg files in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44717164/unable-to-import-svg-files-in-typescript)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

**There should be a `react-app-env.d.ts` file in your `src` folder.** 
If you don't see it, Create a new file in `src` folder named `react-app-env.d.ts`.

Now, just add the code below in your `react-app-env.d.ts` file.

```
declare module "*.png";
declare module "*.svg";
declare module "*.jpeg";
declare module "*.jpg";
```

and you are good to go :)

Comment: i do not see such a file in my project? i added a file with that name and contents in my src folder and the error is still present

Comment: @Tamjid int should be in your src file .
/// <reference types="react-scripts" />
declare module "*.png";
declare module "*.svg";
declare module "*.jpeg";
declare module "*.jpg";

Comment: ah thank you, i was putting it in the root folder of my project, putting the file in my src folder solved the issue.

Comment: what about react-native?

Comment: @moloudayat
npm i react-native-svg
npm i --save-dev react-native-svg-transformer
or if you are using expo : 
expo init SvgDemoApp
expo install react-native-svg
then 
import { SvgUri } from 'react-native-svg';
<SvgUri
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    uri="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/debian.svg"
/>

Comment: @moloudayat https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-svgs-react-native-tutorial-with-examples/

Answer (score 0):

I created a folder in the root of project called '@types', after that i create a file called 'png.d.ts' and added the code 'declare module "*.png"'. That has solved my problem

Comment: This got it to compile, but not run.

Answer (score 0):

I created a folder in the root of project called '@types', after that i create a file called 'png.d.ts' and added the code 'declare module "*.png"'. That has solved my problem
if you have used jpg also than you can also add declare module "*.jpg" in your this code file.

this also worked for me

Answer (score -1):

For those worrying about this in expo react native, there's a file named expo-env.d.ts, in it add the following declarations as per needs

```
declare module "*.png";
declare module "*.svg";
declare module "*.jpeg";
declare module "*.jpg";
```

Comment: That is an auto-generated file, it even has the following comment in it: `// NOTE: This file should not be edited and should be in your git ignore`. You should instead create your own `.d-ts` file.