# Export image file as module React TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, image

Let's say I have a folder with an image file and an index file (it acts like a public API), is there a way to reexport the image with another name?.

The folder structure is as following:

```
└── assets/
      ├── index.ts
      └── facebook.png
```

Is there a way to reexport the image file with a name?, like the following:

index.ts:

```
export * as FacebookLogo from "./facebook.png"
```

Edit: The solution was to declare images file type in an module d.ts, following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71099924/cannot-find-module-file-name-png-or-its-corresponding-type-declarations-type).

enviroment.d.ts file:

```
declare module "*.png";
declare module "*.svg";
declare module "*.jpg";
declare module "*.jpeg";
```

Comment: You can [re-export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#re-exporting_aggregating) it. `export { default as FacebookLogo } from "./facebook.png"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `index.js` file of your api folder...

```
import FacebookLogo from './facebook.png';

export {
  FacebookLogo,
  /** other exports */
};
```